PowerQuery M process the Jira Sprint column from API response
I am importing Jira issue data from a filter with the API. /rest/api/2/search?jql=filter=10816
Everything is working except for the handling the Sprints field.  Power BI reads it as a List column, but it cannot expand the fields properly.  I am trying to extract the sprint name.
This statement will expand the value, but I can't access the 'name' field.
#"Expanded sprint" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Renamed Cols", "Sprints"),
which outputs:
com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@7c84f560[id=275,rapidViewId=171,state=ACTIVE,name=PI3 - Sprint 1,startDate=2024-04-22T13:01:00.000-06:00,endDate=2024-05-03T13:01:00.000-06:00,completeDate=,activatedDate=2024-04-22T11:54:37.867-06:00,sequence=275,goal=,synced=false,autoStartStop=false,incompleteIssuesDestinationId=]
Here is an example of the raw API value for a sprint value:
"customfield_10108": [                    "com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@7e043a71[id=275,rapidViewId=171,state=ACTIVE,name=PI3 - Sprint 1,startDate=2024-04-22T13:01:00.000-06:00,endDate=2024-05-03T13:01:00.000-06:00,completeDate=,activatedDate=2024-04-22T11:54:37.867-06:00,sequence=275,goal=,synced=false,autoStartStop=false,incompleteIssuesDestinationId=]"
What are the powerquery steps to get the name or id values?
